# selecting Nodes from XML using Linq to Xml

Tags: c#, xml

Пробую выбрать элемент, используя Linq to Xml

это XML ответ от сервера:

```
<methodResponse>
    <params>
        <param>
            <value>
                <struct>
                    <member>
                        <name>items</name>
                        <value>
                            <array>
                                <data>
                                    <value>
                                        <struct>
                                            <member>
                                                <name>id</name>
                                                <value>
                                                    <int>17</int>
                                                </value>
                                            </member>
                                            <member>
                                                <name>name</name>
                                                <value>
                                                    <string>test2</string>
                                                </value>
                                        </struct>
                                    </value>
                                </data>
                            </array>
                        </value>
                    </member>
                </struct>   
            </value>
        </param>
    </params>
</methodResponse>
```

Мне нужно выбрать (хотя бы вывести)

```
<string>test2</string>
```

name = test2;

and

```
<int>17</int>
```

id = 17

Я пробую это:

```
...
var xml = new XDocument();
var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
xml = XDocument.Parse(result);
...

            var selectors = from elements in xml.Elements("methodResponse").Elements("params").Elements("param")
                            .Elements("value").Elements("struct").Elements("member")
                            select elements;

            foreach (var element in selectors)
            {
                if (element.Element("name").Value == "items")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(element.Element("name"));
                }
            }
```

Результат выполнения: "items"
Как корректно выбрать из xml значения?

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! переведите, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) на русский язык

Comment: XPath в помощь, незачем городить огороды

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;

var doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");

foreach (var member in doc.Descendants("member"))
{
    var name = member.Element("name").Value;
    Console.WriteLine(name);

    var value = member.Element("value");
    var child = (XElement)value.FirstNode;

    if (child.Name == "array")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Type: array");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Type: " + child.Name);
        Console.WriteLine(child.Value);
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Ключевыми элементами являются узлы "member", вот от них и танцуем. Берём имя, а потом проверяем тип первого элемента внутри "value".

Если могут быть вложенные массивы, то проверку следует сделать рекурсивной.

Comment: да, это как раз то, что было нужно, спасибо!